# How to swap neighbouring nodes in a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, swap

I am new to programming and just learning linkedlists, I am trying to swap neighbouring nodes in a list. For example:

```
input 1 2 3 4 5 6 
output 2 1 4 3 6 5
```

I found a solution for swapping data and tried to tweak it to swap nodes, but I cannot get it functioning. Any ideas? Once I initiate the pairWiseSwap, it seems to just loop, see third block.

```
    // Java program to pairwise swap elements of a linked list
class LinkedList {
    Node head; // head of list

    /* Linked list Node*/
    class Node {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d)
        {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }

     public void pairWiseSwap()
    {
        Node temp = head;
        Node swap;


        /* Traverse only till there are atleast 2 nodes left */
        while (temp != null && temp.next != null) {

            /*
            int k = temp.data;
            temp.data = temp.next.data;
            temp.next.data = k;
            temp = temp.next.next;
            */

            // just loops 
            swap = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
            temp.next = swap;
            temp = temp.next.next;

        }
    }

    /* Utility functions */

    /* Inserts a new Node at front of the list. */
    public void push(int new_data)
    {
        /* 1 & 2: Allocate the Node &
                  Put in the data*/
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);

        /* 3. Make next of new Node as head */
        new_node.next = head;

        /* 4. Move the head to point to new Node */
        head = new_node;
    }

    /* Function to print linked list */
    void printList()
    {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    /* Driver program to test above functions */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

        /* Created Linked List 1->2->3->4->5 */
        llist.push(5);
        llist.push(4);
        llist.push(3);
        llist.push(2);
        llist.push(1);

        System.out.println("Linked List before calling pairWiseSwap() ");
        llist.printList();

        llist.pairWiseSwap();

        System.out.println("Linked List after calling pairWiseSwap() ");
        llist.printList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way is to is manipulate the references to the nodes.

```
Node pf; // reference to first node in sequence pointing to Node a
// Node a and Node b are adjacent nodes.

pf -> a -> b -> rest of list

a.next = b.next; // a -> rest of list
b.next = a;      // b -> a
pf.next = b;     // pf -> b
// so now 
pf -> b -> a -> rest of list
```

There may also be edge cases to consider when some `next` references could be null.  So test with border cases to ensure all works regardless of which two adjacent nodes you are `"swapping."`

And if you employee generics in your class declaration you can accomodate any type.

```
class LinkedList<T> {
    Node head; // head of list

    /* Linked list Node*/
    class Node {
        T data;
        Node next;
        Node(T d)
        {
            data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    // rest of class
```

Comment: you're on the money :) double clicked :D

Answer (score 0):

Drawing this out "on paper" helps. I would suggest to use three references: `prev`, `curr` and `next`, that follow eachother through the list:

```
public void pairWiseSwap()
{
    if (head == null || head.next == null) {
        return;
    }
    Node prev = null;
    Node curr = head;
    Node next;
    head = head.next;
    while (curr != null && curr.next != null) {
        next = curr.next;
        if (prev != null) {
            prev.next = next;  // Link the previously swapped pair to the next pair
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
        next = curr.next;   // Save curr.next before changing it
        curr.next = prev;
        curr = next;
    }
    if (prev != null) {
        prev.next = curr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider a recursive solution.

```
public void pairWiseSwap()
{
    head = swapPair(head);      
}

private Node swapPair(Node curr)
{
    if(curr == null || curr.next == null) return curr;
    
    Node next = curr.next;  
    curr.next = next.next;
    next.next = curr;

    curr.next = swapPair(curr.next);
    
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a common code sequence to swap any pair of nodes, adjacent or not. First swap what ever points to the two nodes, then swap the pointers in the nodes. Say you want to swap b and d:

```
non-adjacent nodes:
a -> b -> c -> d -> e
swap a.next and c.next     a -> d ... c -> b
swap b.next and d.next     b -> e ... d -> c
                           a -> d -> c -> b -> e

adjacent nodes:
a -> b -> d -> e
swap a.next and b.next     a -> d ... b -> b
swap b.next and d.next     b -> e ... d -> b
                           a -> d -> b -> e
```

If there is a dummy head node that isn't part of the actual list, then you don't need special code to handle swapping the 1st node with another node. With the above examples, *a* could be the dummy head node, and the actual initial list would start with *b*.